# XPath двойной или вложенный текст в ID

Tags: selenium, xpath

На сайте есть выпадающее меню с текстом: "Power Supply Unit".
Встроенными средствами браузера Хром я определил полный и обычный xpath:

- /html/body/div[5]/div[3]/ul/li[2]
- //*[@id="menu-type"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]

Но для удобства я использую самый простой вид - это

- //*[text()="Power Supply Unit"]

Я хочу реализовать это более правильно, сделав вложение, чтобы искать текст надо было не на всей странице, через *, а с привязкой к ID например. Я предполагал это сделать так: //*[@id="menu-type"][text()="Power Supply Unit"] но ничего не получается.

Вопрос: можно ли использовать 2 селкектора, или надо в одном селекторе как-то объеденить ID вместе с текстом? Подскажите как?

Comment: Как то так, но чего-то не хватает: `//*[@id="menu-type" and contains(text(), 'Power Supply Unit')]`

Answer (score 0):

> `//[@id="menu-type"][text()="Power Supply Unit"]`

Эта строка ищет на странице элементы с `@id="menu-type"` у которых текст равен `Power Supply Unit`

Вам же нужно найти элемент с текстом `Power Supply Unit` который является **дочерним** по отношению к элементу `@id="menu-type"`. Это делается так

```xml
//[@id="menu-type"]//*[contains(text(), "Power Supply Unit")]
```

> Я хочу реализовать это более правильно

А вот на сколько это правильно - большой вопрос. Дело в том, что операция `//` (поиск узла на любом уровне вложенности) очень медленная и трудозатратная. И лучше стараться ее избегать

Comment: Я проверяю от обратного: в браузере вызываю F12, далее по поиску ищу нужный XPath, если его элемент подсвечивается на сайте, то всё ок. В данном случае не подсвечивается, и тест мой заваливается. Я хочу избавиться от * поскольку она указывает что искать надо везде. В моём случае, только внутри айдишника. Я тоже думал, что можно сразу 2 XPathа писать, но нет, так не получается...

Comment: @Igor-Potapov `*` не искать везде, а искать элементы с любым именем, которые удовлетворяют условию.

Comment: @Igor-Potapov Если мой запрос не работает, значит вы что-то недорассказали. Можете дать ссылку на страницу?

Comment: * - она работает если искать по всем элементам сайта, но мне надо, чтобы она работала внутри АйДи. Структура как я писал выше: `/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/ul/li[2]` это полный путь. Это дроп-даун меню - оно и есть ul / li элемент, вот ссылка на скриншотс кодом, сайт локальный: https://fex.net/s/str2pcl

Comment: @Igor-Potapov на скриншоте текст последнего `li` не **равен** `Power Supply Unit`, а **содержит** эту строку. Соответственно вместо сравнения нужно использовать `contains()`. Я отредактировал ответ. А еще лучше искать по значению атрибута `[@data-value = 'PSU']`

Comment: К сожалению не подсвечивается этот элемент, не выберается этот `LI`